# Questions regarding small-sample time series models

Tags: time-series, small-sample

Thanks for your time handling my issues.
I have several time series models to be improved for the same data set.

1. Time series regression

The first model incorporates only 5 time stamps, whereas we can use 9 time stamps, under the purpose of capturing 'recent' trend.
The model is currently defined by regression model, having the time stamp as the sole independent variable.
Considering that a time series regression model with only 5 points is prone to overfitting, I would like to fit penalized regression, such as LASSO or Ridge, with the whole usuable data, which include 9 time points.
Would it be inappropriate approach, or are there other proper approaches?

2. Exponential smoothing method

The second model currently being used is defined by weighted mean of past time points.
The problem is that the weight coefficients are fixed by intuition, without any theoretical consideration.
To improve this model, I came out with idea of applying simple exponential smoothing, which can be seen as a type of weighted mean, but includes a procedure of optimizing the coefficients.
However, applying ExponentialSmoothing function in python, I encountered convergencewarning issue, probably occured because of the lack of data, which caused the alpha coefficient to be exactly zero or one in many cases.
How can I improve current situation?

3. Sample mean

The final approach is to take just the sample mean of past observations.
However, the sample size is considerably small, which makes the convergence rate of sample mean toward the true mean quite slow.
Thus, I tried 'extending' the sample size. The procedure be like :
(1) Estimate the density function using KDE
(2) Applying MCMC method toward the estimated density function, extract larger size of sample
(3) Calculate the mean estimate from extended sample
However, implementing above method by python, the final output is too close to the sample mean drawn from 5 data points.
Is the approach itself is invalid, or there could be improvable points?

Sincerely appreciate for your time and effort.